# App name updated but not on GameCenter

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center, gamekit

I'm having a quite simple problem, but i hadn't found any solution.
I updated my apps name in the AppStore a few weeks ago and just a few days ago i saw that in the GameCenter it didn't change.

Is it something i have to change or should i get in contact with the Apple Support?

Get a look:

[image: Name changed in the iTunes Connect correctly]

[image: Same old name of the app]

Comment: Did you find a way to change the Game Center name ? We're kinda in the same situation, except our app was rejected because of this...

Comment: led, after i updated it again this name issue got resolved.

Comment: Yeah, same for us, looks like it triggered some kind of update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this same problem with an app I was doing work on. What I found was that when I updated the app a second time, the name changed in GameCenter.